# WSO2 ESB Proxy is not parsing POST Arguments

Tags: xml, proxy, esb, wso2-esb

When i am making a request to the proxy(Custom Proxy), the endpoint is just a simple PhP Script, the problem is, that either the post or get arguments are proxied to the server and i have clue what can be the reason for this issue.
The proxy works, because the content of the php script is in the response, but when i try to for example var dumb the post args, the array is empty.
I am confused because it worked before, i already reinstalled the esb, nothing.
I can also tell the php code is working, cause on a direct call to the php script its just working fine.

The Proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="test-passtrough"
   startOnLoad="true"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   transports="http,https">
   <target endpoint="test">
  <inSequence>
     <log category="DEBUG" level="full"/>
  </inSequence>
  </target>
 <description/>
</proxy>
```

The endpoint:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test">
<http uri-template="http://192.168.5.39/test.php" method="post">
  <suspendOnFailure>
     <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
  </suspendOnFailure>
  <markForSuspension>
     <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
     <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
  </markForSuspension>
 </http>
</endpoint>
```

**EDIT:**
After a helpful comment i was able to figure out that the ESB does not format the request body in a way that PhP can read it, the whole request of the esb looks like:

```
POST /clinet/test.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=------------------            ------3ad90d70166bf83b
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: 192.168.5.34:80
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO

95
--------------------------3ad90d70166bf83b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x"

Test Argument
--------------------------3ad90d70166bf83b--

0
```

Regards Liz3

Comment: you can use tcpmon to see what you are sending to the php script from your proxy...

Comment: Thank you so much! Also if your Comment did not solve the problem it self, i found out that, infact the esb format the request body wrongly, also i noticed, it did not set the content length?!
Regards Liz3

Comment: glad to help you...in those scenarios this is my first test..use the tcpmon to see what happen.

Comment: you can update the question with the new information you found to try to fix the problem